# How to grant Permissions to user project wise in Jira

Tags: permissions, jira, project-management, roles, taskmanager

I have two projects. I need to assign some users to project A and some to project B. Issues of Project A should not be visible to user of Project B and vice versa. Only project manager should be able to access and grant permission to project A,project B,project C etc. users.

Answer (score 0):

JIRA is quite flexible about how you grant permissions. You can put people in a group (such as jira-users or jira-developers) and you can also put people in to roles within projects.

For your requirements you should modify the permission scheme used by your two projects. Do something like this:

For the permission browse project allow project role (Users) and the group Project Managers.

For the permission Administer Projects allow the group Project Managers.

Then, add all your Project Managers to the group Project Managers. Next, for Project A, add the users you want to be on this project to the role of Users for Project A. Similarly for Project B, add the users you want to be on this project to the role of Users for Project B.

This now means that anyone who is a Project Manager can administer projects and can also view them. But only users who have been given a Users role on a project will be able to see them and users that are not Project Managers will not be able to administer anything.

This is just an example of the kind of approach you can take. Experiment with putting users in groups (which you do in the User Management menu) and with adding users to roles (which you do in the projects administration menu). You will also want to add a new custom permission scheme and make sure that scheme is used by each of the projects.

[This Atlassian page covers configuring permissions in more detail](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/managing-project-permissions-185729636.html)